# Test whether the study population come from a normal or log-normal distribution based on mean, median, and number of subjects

Tags: r, normality-assumption, lognormal-distribution

I have MEAN, MEDIAN, NSUB (number of subjects) and SD data coming from different studies and different populations. These are the only available information in the studies. My data set contains the following columns:

```
STUDY   NSUB   MEAN   MEDIAN   SD
1       10     1.5    1.7      0.4
2       20     1.5    1.55     0.3
3       7      2.6    3        0.5
4       15     3      3.01     0.1
```

And so on.

I want to judge whether the mean and median are significantly different at significance level (alpha=0.05). This is so I can make a decision whether the data from each study were come from a normal or log-normal distribution.

I thought of doing a two sided t-test. My hypothesis would be:

NULL: H0: `MEAN=MEDIAN`

Alternative: `HA: MEAN doesn't equal MEDIAN`

The standard error of the mean (SEM) can be calculated as SD/NSUB where NSUB is the number of subjects. The degree of freedom would be NSUB-1. The scenario I am presenting here is as if I am comparing two means that have the same standard deviation (SD).

Is there a way where I can apply this automatically in R for the set of data that I have and have the result added to the data as t.test.result being TRUE/FALSE (significantly different/insignificantly different). Something close to this:

```
STUDY   NSUB   MEAN   MEDIAN   SD     t.test.result
1       10     1.5    1.7      0.4    RESULT1?
2       20     1.5    1.55     0.3    RESULT2?
3       7      2.6    3        0.5    RESULT3?
4       15     3      3.01     0.1    RESULT4?
```

Also, is there a better way to test whether each study population was come from a normal or log-normal distribution?

Comment: Comparing single observation will not have enough degree of freedom

Comment: @akrun The degree of freedom is NSUB-1. The question is as if I am comparing two means that have the same SD

Comment: Why don't you provide few more lines instead of asking others to prepare the example data to test

Comment: @akrun I did add few more lines in the data

Comment: If I look at your edited code, the SD column are all different, ie. only one observation for the MEAN and MEDIAN to compare.  I meant that providing a reproducible example so that there are multiple SD values that are same, if there is only a single observation to return NA?

Comment: @akrun I am not sure if you are getting me right. But I mean is to apply the t.test on the mean and median for study one, get the result whether they are significantly different. Then move an apply it on study 2,3 etc. For example: the t-cal-value for study 1 would be `(1.5-1.7)/(0.4/sqrt(10))`. Then at degree of freedom `10-1=9` and `alpha=0.05`, the t-value (from table) is 2.262. Therefore, the mean and median are not significantly different in this case because t-cal value will bot be within the rejection area.

Comment: This is not how you check whether your data are log-normal v. normal. The median and mean could be different for many reasons.

Comment: @John Do you have any other way? This is the only information I have from the studies.

Comment: @bunk Yes. I am just looking for a way to do this in R instead of doing it manually. I have a large data set.

Comment: Yes, there are other alternatives even with just this data. The N allows one to simulate the two possibilities and check for most likely fits. This really should be reframed to become a CrossValidated question. When you do that you should be also discussing whether these samples are from the same or different population distributions. Because if they come from the same population checking each one for normality is probably pointless. But it means that the reason should be in the question too.

Comment: Why do you want to compare mean and median? For symmetric distributions (like $t$ or Normal)  mean = median. If distribution of your data is skewed that there is a question of validity of $t$-test with such data. In this case, question if mean = median is the same as asking if there are any significant outliers in the data.

Comment: I have merged the migrated duplicate in with this question in order to retain the comments, a few of which may have some value.

Answer (score -2):

Since the two-sided t-test is the only one suggested at this point, I got a naive way of doing this in R:

First: find out t.critical values based on the degree of freedom in each study at significance level 0.05:

```
df$t.critical <- qt(1-0.05/2, df$NSUB-1)
```

Second: Calculate t.test values:

```
df$t.test <- abs(MEAN-MEDIAN)/(SD/sqrt(NSUB))
```

Third: If t.test < t.critical then add a FLAG==0 (meaning; the MEAN and MEDIAN are not significantly different and hence the population can be assumed normal). Otherwise, it is non-normal (i.e. log-normal distribution) and give it FLAG==1

```
df$FLAG <- ifelse(df$t.test <- df$t.critical, 0,1)
```

Comment: This is incorrect because the mean and median are (strongly) correlated, whence the standard error of the mean will be (much) larger than the standard error of the mean minus the median, causing your test statistic to be smaller than it should be.  Moreover, the absolute value doesn't belong here: the difference will tend to be *positive* for a lognormal distribution, with negative values tending to indicate non-lognormality.  Instead, *remove the absolute value* and use numerical integration or simulation to determine a suitable threshold for distinguishing the distributions.